# How do I know if I run hw raid 1?

Tags: linux, raid, hardware-raid, raid1, proxmox

I created a hw raid 1 using efi.

Server Dell PowerEdge T20 with Proxmox

The raid controller is 00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)

```
root@pve:~# lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk 
sdb                            8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk 
sdc                            8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
```

This confuses me. I expected to see sda only. Is this how it is supposed to be?

EDIT: [I pressed the initialize button und now only sda is initilialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtcUG.png)
That doesn't look right.

Comment: Thank you guys. Since I'm running proxmox, most common software solutions are not recommended. The solutions seems to use a ZFS cluster.

Answer (score 3):

If you see the single disk block devices exported to your OS (as in your case) you are *not* running with "HW RAID" turned on.

However, please *really* pay attention on what HW RAID means in this context. Intel's chipsets RAID feature require basically no dedicated hardware. They are nothing more than a firmware-level software RAID, with the lone advantage (in respect to SW RAID) of "masking" the single disks, presenting instead a single volume to both the system BIOS (for a bootable array) and the OS.

As a side note, I generally completely avoid those firmware-level fakeraid, using instead the much more capable Linux MDRAID or ZFS mirrors.

Comment: +1 for software RAID over HW RAID - there's no performance benefit and no dependency on the availability of hardware to read your disks.

Answer (score 1):

During server reboot you should be able to access the RAID utility by pressing a certain key combination.

In there you should be able to determine the RAID type.

Answer (score 0):

Chipset RAID is host RAID, no hardware RAID. Host RAID realizes its function by a combination of port hardware (less) and driver (more). Linux likely just ignores BIOS settings, bypasses the RAID setup and accesses the ports directly, breaking whatever RAID you've built in BIOS. This is a typical danger of host RAID.

With Linux, I wouldn't use host RAID at all (switch SATA ports to *AHCI* in BIOS) but an `mdadm` software RAID.